# Is a profinite free product of pro-$p$ groups a pro-$p$ group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

I have a question. Maybe it be trivial, but I'm cannot conclude nothing yet.

Suppose that we have a free profinite product
$$G = G_1 \amalg \cdots \amalg G_n.$$
By definition in Ribes-Zalesskii $G$ is a profinite group. If all $G_i$ becomes to another category, is also $G$? I'm interested in the case when each $G_i$ is a pro-$p$ group (same $p$ for all $G_i$). Will be $G$ a pro-$p$ group?

Comment: This is already not true for ordinary groups, e.g. the free product of two copies of $C_p$ is not a $p$-group, because there's no reason that the product of two elements of order $p$ needs to have order $p$ (or any finite order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For instance, $S_3$ is generated by two transpositions, so the profinite free product of two cyclic groups of order 2 is not a pro-2-group since it has an epimorphism to $S_3$.